# Issue in dynamically font file url in angular 4

Tags: html, css

My font file path save in database and when site load then @font-face url load from database. code is below

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'Robototext'; 
    src: url('http://10.0.0.189:4000/1078/Webshop/Font/ARIALBD_1533892648708.TTF') format('ttf'); 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: 500;
 }
```

and In Html page load that Font-family name like as below

```
<body style="font-family: 'robototext';">
<div class="wrapper clearfix" id="wrapper">

</div>
</body>
```

But Its not working for me
In my style.css

```
body {
 Font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}
```

it was over rights when see in inspect element but actual "ARIALBD_1533892648708.TTF" not loading in that.

can you help me for what's wrong that and please help me in that issues

Comment: Have you included the styles file in the html? Also, it's `font-family` not `Font-family`

Comment: Yes, Its included, and its font-family

Comment: Issue was resolved it. I have problem with IIS server access origin error prevent to access font file. now its resolved

Answer (score 0):

In your `@font-face`, you set `font-family: 'Robototext';` but in your css, you are using `Font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif`. `Roboto` isn't the same as `Robototext`.

Try this in your css file.

`font-family: "Robototext", sans-serif;`

Comment: but in inspect element its should be overright that css file "font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif" and only shows "font-family: "Robototext", sans-serif;" beacuse i wrote it in body tage